# FTP transfer issue

Tags: linux, bash, ftp

I am building FTP bash script to generate a .csv file and  transfer from a Linux machine to another server, but i have problems because it tigers an error and the file is not transferred on the 2nd server. What could be the problem?

This is the error:

`TEST: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
Filename invalid`

And it doesn't matter if i put the / before the TEST, it will trigger the same issue.

This is my script

```
HOST='ipadress'
USER='user'
PASSWD=''
TARGET='TEST'

#Paramenters
set -x
DATE=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`
SQL=/home/sql_statement.sql
QUERYCMD=/home/report.sh
CSV=/home/csv/test_$DATE.csv


#Interogate the sql and put in the folder
$QUERYCMD ${SQL} ${CSV}

#Send the .csv file in the target folder
cd /home/csv
ftp -n  $HOST <<EOF
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
lcd $TARGET
put $CSV $TARGET
quit
EOF
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does the symbol TARGET refer to a dir on the remote host?

`ftp` command `lcd` would change-dir on the local (client) side, while `cd` would change-dir on the remote (server) side; also for the remote side there's usually a designated `ftp root` dir, adjust any path in relation to that starting point; to confirm dir contents, you might add `ftp` commands `ls` and `!ls` on separate lines right after the `PASS` line